# Convex and concave functions of three variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How can I test the function for three variables if it is convex or concave

Consider
$$f(x,y,z)=xz-xyz$$ whete x,y and z $\in (- \infty,\infty) $

A function ƒ is convex or concave if the Hessian
matrix of ƒ  $H(f)$ is positive definite or  negative definite respectively for all values of x, y and z.

then we get the Hessian matrix of ƒ as following,

$H(f)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -z & 1-y \\
 -z & 0 & -x \\
 1-y & -x & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

since the determinate of $H(f)$ 
$$D(H(f))=2 x z - 2 x y z$$

since all critical points of $f(x,y,z)$ are $\{(0, 1, z), (0, y, 0), (x, 1, 0)\}$

In this test I can not determine whether the function is positive definite or  negative definite.

Is there another test or correction of the method?

Can I use this theory
[image]

where $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $

Suppose we want to compute the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $H(f)$

$H(f)-\lambda I=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\lambda  & -z & 1-y \\
 -z & -\lambda  & -x \\
 1-y & -x & -\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)$

We now compute the determinant of $H(f)-\lambda I$

$$-\lambda ^3+\lambda +\lambda  x^2-2 x y z+2 x z+\lambda 
   y^2-2 \lambda  y+\lambda  z^2$$
[image]

> From the 2nd derivative test. The Hessian matrix of $f$  which has negative determinant
>
> Is $f$ neither concave nor convex?

Comment: It is nonnegative. All minuses must be plus in $\Delta$.

Comment: @farruhota  can you test the function f  is convex or concave

Comment: @farruhota  Function $$f(x,y,z)=xz-xyz$$ see new update

Comment: For $f(x,y)=xz+xyz$, $|H|=2xz(1+y)$ and $f(x,y)=xz-xyz$, $|H|=2xz(1-y)$. Now, cases must be considered like $x,z,1+y>0$, etc

Comment: Note $|H_2|=-z^2<0$, $|H_3|=2xz(1-y)>0$ for $x,z,1-y>0; x,z<0,1-y>0; x,1-y<0,z>0;z,1-y<0,x>0$ it is concave.

Comment: @farruhota Can you explain the comment in an answer.
What do you mean by $|H_2|$ and $|H_3|$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63616/discussion-between-emad-kareem-and-farruhota).

Comment: Can't you just find the eigenvalues of $H$ and express the condition that all are nonnegative in terms of inequalities on $x$, $y$, and $z$? The characteristic equation is a depressed cubic (which, thanks to the symmetry, has no complex roots), so the computation might be a bit tedious.

Comment: @Kajelad Can you explain the comment in an answer. Please explain how to answer. Or
  Little reference

Comment: Are you familiar with the process of finding eigenvalues using the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial)? The Hessian is positive definite iff its eigenvalues are all nonegative, and we can find the eigenvalues explicitly in terms of $x$, $y$, and $z$ by finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial. There may be a more convenient way to determine the signs of the eigenvalues, as there is in $\mathbb R^2$, but simply finding them would be the obvious approach.

Comment: @Kajelad see new update

Comment: @zhw Why did you delete the answer

Answer (score 5):

While I appreciate Kajelad's thoroughness, there's a much simpler way to look at this *if* you are simply trying to confirm whether the function is convex or concave or neither. Again, the Hessian is
$$H=\begin{bmatrix}
0   & -z & 1-y \\
-z  & 0  & -x  \\
1-y & -x & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
The diagonal has all zero values. That means the *sum* of the eigenvalues, which is equal to the trace of the matrix, is also zero. So we have only two choices:

1. All of the eigenvalues are zero---i.e., the entire matrix is zero.
2. There is at least one positive eigenvalue and one negative eigenvalue.

Option 1 is true only when $x=z=0$ and $y=1$. Everywhere else, we have option 2. Therefore, the Hessian is *indefinite* almost everywhere, and the function is neither convex nor concave.

Answer (score 1):

You have already found the hessian of $f$, which is well defined everywhere.

$$H=\begin{bmatrix}
0   & -z & 1-y \\
-z  & 0  & -x  \\
1-y & -x & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

To show that $f$ is convex on a convex domain, it is sufficient to show that $H$ is positive semidefinite on that domain's interior, or, equivalently, that the eigenvalues of $H$ are all nonegative on the interior. We can find the eigenvalues, but this requires a lot of messy algebra, and all we really need is their signs. Because $H$ is symmetric, we can instead use the positive semidefinite case of [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), which states that $H$ is positive semidefinite iff all the principle minors of $H$ have nonnegative determinants. That is,

$$\det\left({\begin{bmatrix}
0   & -z & 1-y \\
-z  & 0  & -x  \\
1-y & -x & 0
\end{bmatrix}}\right)\ge 0$$

$$\det\left({\begin{bmatrix}
0  & -x  \\
-x & 0
\end{bmatrix}}\right)\ge 0$$

$$\det\left({\begin{bmatrix}
0   & 1-y \\
1-y & 0
\end{bmatrix}}\right)\ge 0$$

$$\det\left({\begin{bmatrix}
0   & -z \\
-z  & 0
\end{bmatrix}}\right)\ge 0$$

Evaluating determinants:

$$-2x(y-1)z\ge 0$$

$$-x^2\ge 0$$

$$-(y-1)^2\ge 0$$

$$-z^2\ge 0$$

From this, we see that $H$ is positive semidefinite only at the point $(x, y, z)=(0, 1, 0)$. Since this set has no interior, $f$ is not convex anywhere for the typical definition of a convex function of several variables.

To find where $f$ is concave, we determine where $-f$ is convex, which in turn implies $-H$ is positive semidefinite. This only reverses the first inequality, and we obtain the same result, that $f$ is not concave anywhere.

Comment: Hmm, there must be a mistake in your derivation. It is not the case that $H$ is positive semidefinite on the line $x=z=0$. Try $x=y=z=0$, for instance; it is indefinite there. As I show above, it's indefinite everywhere it is not zero. I see it's because you forgot the third determinant in your list.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the error; In writing out the answer I neglected to write the 3rd determinant as an inequality. As you pointed out, $H$ is indeed indefinite everywhere that it is nonzero.